# How to get quota/metrics/reads/writes of current month using nodejs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a local task, using Node JS. I need to fetch the current usage of reads/writes of Firestore to programmatically calculate the monthly payment, but I haven't found any way to fetch this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking to fetch the document/read_count & document/write_count metrics (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-firestore).